# Is December somehow special in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I count the number of transactions made per month

```
=if(COUNTIF(ArrayFormula(month(
        indirect($H$12&"!$F$3:F")
        )),10)
=0,"",COUNTIF(ArrayFormula(month(
        indirect($H$12&"!$F$3:F")
        )),10)
)
```

Where `10` is `October`, while referencing a sheet named in `$H$12`. This works well for months 1-11.

When it comes to December, I am getting a seemingly random (wrong) integer back.

Is December somehow special?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `Filter`. Seems to work perfectly fine

`=COUNTA(filter(indirect($H$12&"!$A$3:A"),month(indirect($H$12&"!$F$3:F"))=10))`